# Watir following_sibling Not Seeing Element

Tags: html, watir

I'm trying to get an element's text and it somehow isn't working.

````
## html:
<table class="infobox vcard">
(snip)
<tbody>
<tr>(stuff)</tr>
<tr>(stuff)</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row" class="infobox-label" style="padding-right: 0.5em;">Website</th>
  <td class="infobox-data" style="line-height: 1.35em;">
    <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="https://group.pingan.com">https://group.pingan.com</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>(stuff)</tr>
</tbody>


## code:
website = b.element(class: 'vcard').element(visible: 'Website').following_sibling(index: 1).text

## error:
/Users/rich/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/watir-7.1.0/lib/watir/locators/element/selector_builder.rb:149:in `raise_unless': expected one of [TrueClass, FalseClass], got "Website":String (TypeError)
```
That line with the text "Website" is the only `row` in that `table`, hence why I'm using it.  I though using the `.following_sibling` method would flush this out, but it's not usable for some reason and I don't know why.  This is on `Wikipedia`.  

Anybody know how what I'm doing wrong?  How can I fix this?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. The exception is occurring on `element(visible: 'Website')`. The :visible locator expects either `true` (element can be seen by a person) or `false` (element cannot be seen by a person). As you want to locate the cell on text, use the :text locator.
2. For `following_sibling`, the :index locator is 0-based. Having `index: 1`, is looking for the second sibling, which doesn't exist. The cell with the link is `index: 0`, which is the default so does not need to be explicitly specified.

Putting it together, gives:

```
browser.element(class: 'vcard').element(text: 'Website').following_sibling.text
=> "https://group.pingan.com"
```

Comment: Excellent.  Is there an alternative to using `browser.element`?  Docs say to avoid this.

Comment: The suggestion is to use the specific element method if the element tag is known. You can do `browser.table(class: 'vcard').th(text: 'Website').following_sibling.text`.